Parsing AWS CLI response
I am looking to tidy up a response from aws ec2 cli. Basically want to get a list of ec2 instances terminated because of lack of spot capacity.
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters Name=instance-lifecycle,Values=spot Name=instance-state-name,Values=terminated Name=state-reason-code,Values=Server.SpotInstanceTermination \
    --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[StateTransitionReason, Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]']

This results in:
[
    [
        "i-XXXXXXXX",
        "Service initiated (2024-07-08 10:55:08 GMT)",
        [
            "ec2-main"
        ]
    ]
]

Ideally I'd like it to appear
i-XXXXXXXX, Service initiated (2024-07-08 10:55:08 GMT), ec2-main

Is this possible?

You can use --output text to remove the square brackets, but the comma-formatting won't be easy especially since you are including nested values. You could probably remove that nesting by using Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[] | [0] -- that will choose the first element. If you want to know more about the syntax, see: JMESPath Tutorial — JMESPath

You might be better off with the entire JSON and then pipe it through jq. Or write the equivalent in Python using boto3 in which case you have complete programmatic control.
